# Python error when trying to get Date from yfinance Ticker object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock, yfinance

I am trying to make a daily line graph for certain stocks, but am running into an issue. Getting the 'Close' price every 2 minutes functions correctly, but when I try and get 'Datetime' I am getting an error. I believe yfinance used pandas to create a dataframe, but I may be wrong. Regardless, I am having issues pulling a certain column from yfinance.

I am pretty new to python and many of the packages, so this might be a simple error, but my code is shown below.

```
stock = yf.Ticker('MSFT')
print(stock.history(period='1d', interval='2m'))
priceArray = stock.history(period='1d',interval='2m')['Close']
dateArray = stock.history(period='1d',interval='2m')['Datetime']
```

The error I am getting is:

```
File "C:\Users\TrevorSmith\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3024, in __getitem__ indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  
File "C:\Users\TrevorSmith\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 'Date'
```

When I print the `stock.history(period='1d',interval='2m)` It shows the following column names:

```
Open        High         Low       Close  Volume  Dividends  Stock Splits  Datetime
```

Again, getting ['Close'] from this information works, but ['Date'], ['Datetime'], ['DateTime'], and ['Time'] do not work.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is there another way to get the info I am looking for?

Comment: `KeyError: 'Date'` means no `Date` variable where u looking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datetime is no column name, it just looks like one:

[image]

Try
`print(stock.history(period='1d',interval='2m).keys())`
and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

The Datetime column is the index of the dataframe. If you reset the index you can do whatever with the ['Datetime'] column.